# How to do update with include tag through liquibase command line with war as classpath

Tags: java, mysql, jhipster, liquibase, ubuntu-17.04

### What am I trying to do

I'm trying to run an update on a MySQL database using Liquibase's command line tool and a `.war` file, and it's important to not touch the `master.xml` file unless I absolutely have to as to not break the project run with maven and Jhipster.

### What does my code look like

Following [the official documentations's example](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html) of how to set up the path:

```
java -jar liquibase.jar \
      --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
      --classpath=website.war \
      --changeLogFile=com/example/db.changelog.xml \
      --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracle \
      --username=scott \
      --password=tiger \
      update
```

I made my liquibase.properties as following:

```
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
username=username
password=password
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
classpath=target/application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml
```

My `master.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

And my commandline command looks like this:

```
liquibase --defaultsFile=../dev.properties update
```

### What's the error

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
```

And of course nothing happens. Liquibase runs it's startup just fine so there's the `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` table in the database.

### What I've tried

I've tried editing my `changeLogFile` property to the following:

```
changeLogFile=/home/user/project_src/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml
changeLogFile=WEB-INF/classes/config/liquibase/master.xml
```

However, these return the same error message. If I try to use the exact path on my system to the changefile I, of course get this:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: /home/user/project_src/~/project_src/src/main/resources does not exist

SEVERE 5/19/17 9:38 AM: liquibase: /home/user/project_src/~/project_src/src/main/resources does not exist
liquibase.exception.CommandLineParsingException: /home/user/project_src/~/project_src/src/main/resources does not exist
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.configureClassLoader(Main.java:828)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:187)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I've also tried to edit the `master.xml` to make the include tag look like this:

```
<include file="changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

This does work for the command line tool, but since this is also run through maven and Jhipster I'd rather not manipulate this file unless I have to.

All the mentioned technologies are the latest stable versions from their dists and I've had this issue on Ubuntu 16.10 and 17.04.

### A workaround I've gotten to work

If I put a changefile path directly instead of the `master.xml` it runs beautifully with **any of the above listed versions of the path**, but then I'd have to run each change log manually completely losing the point of the `master.xml` and its `include` tag.

#### Other information

The project was generated using Jhipster.